# Is there a JQuery plugin that will turn a color photo to a b&w photo on upload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jcrop when users upload a photo for their avatar to resize it properly.. however I'd also like to turn the photos black & white.

Answer (score 4):

You can turn it [black and white on the client side, with canvas](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/jsCanvasGrayscale/index.html), but it would be pointless to push this pixel data to the server to be saved. I would use this only as a preview to the user.

If you wanted them to be permanently black and white, do it server side.

Comment: +1 for do it server side. no point in doing image manipulation on the client

Comment: why not? it cuts down on the byte size when sending to a server.

Comment: @Anurag You may expect a grayscale image, but the client could send anything. Validating it on the server-side would then be pointless when you could just generate it on the server-side.

Comment: validating the image on the server side again may not be totally pointless, if most clients are high-latency or there are significant cuts in payload size, resulting in faster uploads and a better overall experience for the end user.

Comment: You never want to destroy data. Keep the original file so the user can run additional effects if desired.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it server-side. I believe jCrop comes with php as it's back-end, so maybe this link helps.

[How do you convert an image to black and white in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254388/how-do-you-convert-an-image-to-black-and-white-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Look http://www.pixastic.com/

Answer (score 0):

An alternative idea: You can do this in flash (although requires flash)

Answer (score 0):

Webdesigner wall has a [good tutorial](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/html5-grayscale-image-hover/) on using jQuery and Canvas to apply a grayscale effect client-side.