# How to Black and White Image in PHP?

Tags: php

How to Black and White Image in PHP not just grey scale, thank you for consideration i hope you could help me!

Comment: IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE: Converts the image into grayscale. ?

Comment: Theres a similar question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254388/how-do-you-convert-an-image-to-black-and-white-in-php

Comment: i cant understand the code in that link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `imagefilter()` function, first with `IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE` to make it grayscale, then with `IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST` to make it full black and white.

Answer (score 0):

Use `imagefilter` function.
[Go see it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php)

From PHP documentation:

`IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE: Like IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE, except you can specify the color. Use arg1, arg2 and arg3 in the form of red, green, blue and arg4 for the alpha channel. The range for each color is 0 to 255.`

Use the arguments to adjust your black and white.

P.S. When asking questions in the future, please add more details and what have you achieved so far.